# Handling of Non-Existing Properties in Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

This is from the category "unexpected behavior" - take the following query (you can paste it in Graph Explorer):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=idc eq 'test'
```

This returns status code 400 and "Property 'idc' does not exist as a declared property or extension property." Which is a sensible and understandable response.

Now, if try to $select this property:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=idc
```

I get a result I totally don't expect:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(idc)",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=idc&$skiptoken=cut",
    "value": [
        {},
        {},
...
        {}
    ]
}
```

(a list of empty objects; asking for a single user with that invalid property name returns me an emtpy response).

So my question is - why does $filter error out and $select does not? Would there be a way to force $select to error out too? (eg I am using the /beta endpoint and a property name changes - I want my code to fail to find out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer.  We had a discussion on this and would love to get some of your thoughts (and the thoughts of other developers). We don't have a clear answer on this yet.

There are 2 schools of thought here:

1. Make $select and $filter behave consistently when dealing with properties that don't exist.
2. It's OK for these to differ in behavior, since the caller’s intent when specifying $select is likely different than that of $filter. The service cannot ignore a property specified in $filter because it completely changes the set of objects that are returned. However, $select does not change the set of objects but only drops the properties that are not available. Hence $select and $filter do not need to be consistent.

Thoughts?

Hope this helps,

Comment: I lean towards #1 - it saves me the time figuring out what I did wrong when some property is not returned as I would have expected. If, however, the decision goes to #2: at least call out the behavioral differences in a way nobody is caught by surprise.

Comment: I would also say #1, even tho both scenarios make sense the way you described, I think similar behavior (throwing error on non-existing properties) eliminates all confusion, maybe even save some people from typos : )